# Is there a way to get deep linking data without setting webhook?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

When creating a bot, I ran into a problem. I want to passing additional parameters to the bot on startup, so deep linking can help me, but all my code uses Update method to get data.
 `t.me/@SomeBot?start=some_data`
How can I get data **without** using webhook? Or is there any way to use `python-telegram-bot` methods to get that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deep Linking has nothing to do with Webhooks. You can have them even with polling Updates. Here is an [example in library](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/blob/master/examples/deeplinking.py).